# how to apply xs:unique to two objects

Tags: xsd

I am trying to write xs:unique for my xsd to constrain the name for container and list objects have unique name, but could not make it work. Could you help?

Here are the details

My object structure is like the following tree.

```
App 
  |
  ---container
        |
         --list
              |
               ---container
                     |
                     --list
```

Each "container " can have 0 or more "list" and each "list" can have 0 or more "container". Both list and container have "name" attribute and other different attributes. I would like to constrain that the "name" is unique for both container and list for the entire instance. How should I write the unique selector xpath? Here is the schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:my_app="http://www.cisco.com/myapp" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="app">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="container" type="containerType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniquename">
        <xs:selector xpath=""/>
        <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="listType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="container" type="containerType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="containerType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="list" type="listType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
<xs:selector xpath="//container | //list"/>
```

Comment: I tried this but my xmlspy raise an error: "The xpath attribute value '//container | //list' is not a valid restricted XPath expression."

Comment: Try omitting the white space; it's legal, but it's the kind of thing some XPath parsers don't know they should accept.

Comment: I got the same error with/without white space. It does not like '//'. However, the xmlspy tool could recognize "//container | //list" in other context. Do you know any tool (API) that could recognize the constrain?

Answer (score 0):

C.M.Sperberg-McQueen it almost right. The problem with the restricted XPath syntax (as seen in section 3.11.16 for [XSD 1.0 Structures](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1)) is that in your case it requires to start with a . (dot).

So the correct solution is

```
    <xs:selector xpath=".//container|.//list"/>
```

@C.M.Sperberg-McQueen is also right in stating that the whitespace is legal and should not cause any issues. I confirm that stock Java and .NET validators have no issues with the above (with or w/o whitespaces). The XML below becomes invalid if you duplicate the value of your name attribute at any level.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:my_app="http://www.cisco.com/myapp">
    <container name="anySimpleType1">
        <list name="anySimpleType2">
            <container name="anySimpleType3">
                <list name="anySimpleType4">
                    <container name="anySimpleType5">
                        <list name="anySimpleType6"/>
                        <list name="anySimpleType7"/>
                    </container>
                    <container name="anySimpleType8">
                        <list name="anySimpleType9"/>
                        <list name="anySimpleType10"/>
                    </container>
                </list>
                <list name="anySimpleType11">
                    <container name="anySimpleType12">
                        <list name="anySimpleType13"/>
                        <list name="anySimpleType14"/>
                    </container>
                </list>
            </container>
            <container name="anySimpleType16">
                <list name="anySimpleType17">
                    <container name="anySimpleType18">
                        <list name="anySimpleType19"/>
                        <list name="anySimpleType20"/>
                    </container>
                </list>
            </container>
        </list>
    </container>
</app>
```